# how do I find the value inside of a td upon clicking a checkbox in another td but within the same tr?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a table with a few columns and a few rows. When I click a checkbox at the beginning of each row, I'd like to store the value of a particular cell into a variable and use it in a comparison for something else.

How would I go about getting data from a cell in the same row as the clicked checkbox?

This function gets called by the click event for the checkbox that was clicked

```
 function checkLives
 if ($('.CarrierID:contains("2")', $( ':checkbox' ).parents( 'td' ) ).length > 0 )
        {
            //if its not dental
            <%if (this.CurrentProduct != Products.Dental){%>

                //if the lives being quoted are over 16

                //Here is where I would need the value inside of that table row
                if (livesover16)
                {
                    //show popup
                  $('#over16').dialog('open');
                    return false;

            <%}%>
        }
```

Comment: Let's see the the HTML for the page (not the server-side code to generate it, the actual HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (hard to be more precise without seeing the html):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(){

     var tdtext = $(this) //the current clicked chexbox
                   .closest('tr') //the wrapping tr of the chechbox
                   .find('td') //find the td
                   .text(); //get the text 
});
```